# CSS Spacing of News Release Links

Tags: css, web, feed

I am just looking to space these news releases out nicely so there is a gap in between each posting. I have included an image below to explain. I tried to increase the padding on the following but that did not work. Thanks for the help

```
.headline {
position: absolute;
padding-top: 15px;
}
```

http://www.petrowestcorp.com/home/

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Made your press releases look like the following:

```
.feedburnerFeedBlock ul li {
  list-style-type: none;
  text-align: left;
  font-size: 12px;
  line-height: 1.5em;
  overflow: auto;
  padding-top: 10px;
}
```

Here is what I made it look like with the above css code:

[image]

As suggested elsewhere in the answers, your span cannot be given padding-top/bottom unless you explicitly set its display property to behave like block/inline-block level elements. Hence, instead of setting that property on `span`, we set it to the `li` tag. However, i added `overflow:auto` as well because your css did not contain its elements as you had set `position:absolute` to your spans. This could should set that bit right as well.

Answer (score 0):

Hi you can simply do this in css.

```
.feedburnerFeedBlock > ul > li {
    padding-top: 15px;
}
```

A `span` element is not a `block` element and u can only apply dimensions if u set the span to e.g. `display: block`

Answer (score 0):

This [JSfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/StDMS/) should work well for you.

**HTML**

```
<div class='feedburnerFeedBlock'>
    <ul>
        <li>
             <h6>August 13, 2013</h6>

            <p><a href='#'>Petrowest Corporation Announces Second Quarter 2013 Financial Results and New Contract Award for Civil Division</a>
            </p>
        </li>
        <li>
             <h6>May 13, 2013</h6>

            <p><a href='#'>Petrowest Corporation Announces First Quarter 2013 Financial Results</a>
            </p>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
a {
    color: #000;
    text-decoration: none;
}
h6, p {
    font-family:'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    font-size: 12px;
    font-weight: normal;
    line-height: 1.5;
}
h6, p, .feedburnerFeedBlock ul, .feedburnerFeedBlock ul li {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
h6 {
    color: #777;
}
.feedburnerFeedBlock ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 10px 0;
    width: 320px;
}
.feedburnerFeedBlock ul li {
    margin-bottom: 15px;
}
```